# DataTables Ultimate date / time sorting plug-in not working with Intl formats

Tags: datatables

I am trying to sort date columns using the Ultimate date / time sorting plug-in ( https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18 )

The columns are correctly displaying the into formatted dates, Invaded the datetime-moment.js file and as per the documentation , I added :

```
    $(document).ready(function() {  
         $.fn.dataTable.moment( 'LL', locale );
         $.fn.dataTable.moment( 'L h:mm', locale );
```

My DataTables default initialization is :

```
    $.extend( true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
      dom: "<'row'<'col-xs-6'><'col-xs-6'f>r>t<'row'<'col-xs-6'l><'col-xs-6'p>>", 
      language: { url: langUrl },
      searching: true,
      ordering: true,
      paging: true,
      info: false,
      select: true
    } );
```

and the ColumnDefs, with the Intl date formats  are :

```
     columnDefs:  {
           targets: column_date,
           type: 'date',
           render: function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
             if(data){
               var mDate = moment(data);
               return (mDate && mDate.isValid()) ? mDate.format("LL") : "";
             }
             return "";
           }
         },
         {
           targets: column_time,
           type: 'date',
           render: function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
             if(data){
               var mDate = moment(data);
               return (mDate && mDate.isValid()) ? mDate.format("L h:mm") : "";
             }
             return "";
           }
         },
```

All data in these columns have this kind of values to be displayed :

```
         "Dernière Utilisation":"2015-09-21",
         "Dernière Connexion":"2015-09-21 15:24",
```

and I got correctly displayed , not sorted correctly

[image: table]

Am I wrong ? or is it a bug ? this plugin is working fine in 'en' locale'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're using [Ultimate date/time sorting plug-in](https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18) differently than described in the article.

Use the following code for the `columnDefs` option:

```js
columnDefs:  
     {
       targets: column_date,
       render: function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
          if(type === 'display'){
             if(data){
                var mDate = moment(data);
                data = (mDate && mDate.isValid()) ? mDate.format("LL") : "";
             }
         }

         return data;
       }
     },
     {
       targets: column_time,
       render: function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
         if(type === 'display'){
            if(data){
               var mDate = moment(data);
               data = (mDate && mDate.isValid()) ? mDate.format("L h:mm") : "";
            }
         }

         return data;
       }
     },
```

I believe you can remove the following lines:

```
$.fn.dataTable.moment( 'LL', locale );
$.fn.dataTable.moment( 'L h:mm', locale );
```