# jQuery Datatables Ultimate Date/Time Sorting Plugin

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

We are using the Datatables ultimate date/time sorting plugin (https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18) to try and sort date columns, but not having any luck getting it to properly sort dates in the right format. When the page loads, the following script is run:

```
//sets the date format for datatables for sorting purposes
//reference: https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18
$.fn.dataTable.moment( 'M/D/YYYY' );

/* Datatables */
$('.datatable').DataTable({
    language : {
        search : "_INPUT_",
        searchPlaceholder : "Search...",
        paginate : {
            "next" : '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>',
            "previous" : '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>'
        }
    },
    responsive : {
        details : {
            display : $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.display.childRowImmediate,
            type : 'column'
        }
    },
    order : [0, 'desc'],

  //date sorting
  columnDefs:
  {
    targets: 'date_sortable',
    render: function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
      if(type === 'display'){
         if(data){
            var mDate = moment(data);
            data = (mDate && mDate.isValid()) ? mDate.format("M/D/YYYY") : "";
            console.log('rewrote data to ' + data);
         }
     }
      console.log('date_sortable rendered');
     return data;
   }
  }
});
```

According to both the Datatables documentation and the details I found on this SO post ([DataTables Ultimate date / time sorting plug-in not working with Intl formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32728162/datatables-ultimate-date-time-sorting-plug-in-not-working-with-intl-formats)), I added `date_sortable` as a class name on the `<th />` element in my HTML, but it looks like the `render` function isn't called, as my `console.log[...]` entries never run. I can see in the generated HTML the class is on my `<th />` element, and the dates being shown are in the proper format (`'n/j/Y'`, in PHP) so I'm at a total loss.

Everything looks setup correctly, so any tips/pointers here? The date ordering seems to be rather random in nature, with entries that have dates such as 1/6/2016 showing up in the middle (see screenshot), which makes no sense at all.

I will say this table is showing ~2,055 records so is it possibly a performance thing? This isn't currently loading with API calls, so all records are in the generated HTML as a single file.

[image: Dates showing up in the middle]

Comment: it's not random, it's string sorting instead of numeric. in this example, it's sorted in order as 2, 2, 2, 6, 7

Answer (score 0):

can you look at the unshifted Function in Datatables?

```
// Add type detection
types.detect.unshift( function ( d ) {
return moment( d, format, locale, true ).isValid() ?
    'moment-'+format :
    null;
} );
```

if it's the case, you should use this:

```
$.fn.dataTable.moment('YYYY-M-D');
```

Comment: We are using this to show the data: `<?php echo date('n/j/Y', strtotime($order->OrderDate)); ?>`. Can you clarify what you mean by converting to timestamps and then sorting? Are you saying do this in the PHP somewhere or elsewhere?

Comment: I removed the solution with timestamp as it's a dirty solution! so I'll don't use it for production code!

Comment: I think the moment returned from the unshift function is using the local date format - so the format of your system. This is for sure different from n/j/Y.

Comment: I had tried that format first, but it wasn't working still for some reason. I looked up the API docs for the unshift function, but I'm honestly not following what that is meant to do. Can you clarify this a bit for me? Thanks!

Comment: ok can you write what you have under "types.order[ 'moment-'+format+'-pre' ] = function ( d ) {" in your Datatables code? - or put your code to jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Please try this fiddle (this works with your date format):

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/Marouen/9qdj53am`
```

Hope this will help.